# How do I create a nested For loop to multiply a variable in one data frame by every variable in another data frame, to create a new data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I currently have 2 data frames.

df_A contains a multiplication factor for everyday of the year. e.g.,

| day | multiplication factor |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | 0.004 |
| Jan 2 | 0.007 |
| Jan 3 | 0.005 |
| Jan 4 | 0.007 |

df_B contains yearly volumes across 5 different categories

| Category | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cat 1 | 1000 | xx | xx |  |
| cat 2 | xx | xx | xx | xx |
| cat 3 | xx | xx | xx | xx |
| cat 4 | xx | xx | xx | xx |
| cat 5 | xx | xx | xx | xx |

I require a new data frame that multiples (1) the volume form each year (2) for each category, by the (3) multiplication factor for each day.

e.g for jan 1, cat 1, 2022

1000 * 0.004

The final data frame will look something like:

| Day | category | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jan 1 | cat 1 | 1000 * 0.04 |  |  |
| jan 1 | cat 2 | xx * 0.04 |  |  |
| jan 1 | cat 3 |  |  |  |
| jan1 | cat 4 |  |  |  |
| jan 1 | cat 5 |  |  |  |
| jan 2 | cat 1 |  |  |  |
| jan 2 | cat 2 |  |  |  |
| jan 2 | cat 3 |  |  |  |

Been trying various for loops but does seem to crack it

Answer (score 0):

You can `cross join` the two dataframes by using `merge` to create a cartesian join. After this you can use `dplyr` to multiply your year columns to the multiplication factor.

Here is a working example, you can rearrange the resulting columns if you want:

```
df_A <- readr::read_table(
"day    multiplication_factor
Jan_1   0.004
Jan_2   0.007
Jan_3   0.005
Jan_4   0.007"
)

df_B <- readr::read_table(
"Category 2022  2023  2024  2025
cat_1   1000  1200  1400  1600
cat_2 600 800 1000  1200"
)

library(dplyr)

merge(df_A, df_B) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("20"), ~ .x * multiplication_factor))
#>     day multiplication_factor Category 2022 2023 2024 2025
#> 1 Jan_1                 0.004    cat_1  4.0  4.8  5.6  6.4
#> 2 Jan_2                 0.007    cat_1  7.0  8.4  9.8 11.2
#> 3 Jan_3                 0.005    cat_1  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
#> 4 Jan_4                 0.007    cat_1  7.0  8.4  9.8 11.2
#> 5 Jan_1                 0.004    cat_2  2.4  3.2  4.0  4.8
#> 6 Jan_2                 0.007    cat_2  4.2  5.6  7.0  8.4
#> 7 Jan_3                 0.005    cat_2  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0
#> 8 Jan_4                 0.007    cat_2  4.2  5.6  7.0  8.4
```